# Using structs in fields

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to understand the difference between the case where structs contain simple types vs. when they contain other structs. All guides/examples/... seem to use only basic types as fields and this works:

```
struct Something {
    some: i32,
    numbers: i32,
}
```

But this results in error:

```
struct Something {
    reader: Reader,
    writer: Writer,
}
```

On the current master: `error: explicit lifetime bound required`

So what's the solution here? `Something` is constructed with both `reader` and `writer` and is returned from that function - `reader` and `writer` themselves are not copied anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Reader` and `Writer` are traits and not other structs this is why that code does not work.

What you want to do does work with other structs as you can see [here](http://is.gd/aDQaP4):

```
fn main() {
    #[deriving(Show)]
    struct OtherStruct {
        s: uint,
    }
    #[deriving(Show)]
    struct Something {
        reader: OtherStruct,
    }
    println!("{}" , Something { reader : OtherStruct { s : 10 } });
}
```

For the actual Reader that you want to use you can have a look [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Reader.html#implementors).